# Can I get the Unity3D engine version in Xcode and how to do a conditional compile based on the version?

Tags: ios, xcode, compilation, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a plugin in Unity3D for iOS. For some reason, I need to specify some code in the native code (.mm in Xcode) to be compiled under before Unity3D 4.1 and other be compiled after Unity3D 4.1(including). Maybe something like this:

```
#if UNITY_VERSION < UNITY_4_1
    //Some code be compiled before Unity4.1
#else
    //Some code for new version
#endif
```

I know there is a [Platform Dependent Compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) in the Unity3D Editor, but how can I get the engine's version in Xcode and do a "Unity Engine version based condition compilation"? Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Edit: Maybe I can write two .mm files for different version and delete one of them in [[PostProcessAttribute]](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/PostProcessAttribute.html). But I don't think it is a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't exactly clear on what you are trying to do. Are you building your native code by injecting into the XCode project that Unity creates? Or are you building your native code to a library that is included by Unity during the build?

AFAIK there is no way for XCode to know ahead of time which version of Unity you are using without examing the install of Unity and figuring out a way to determine that.

If you doing the latter, i.e. building a native code library that is included into Unity's build. You would need two separate libraries in that case, and instruct the user to include whichever one is relevant.

If you are doing the former, i.e. injecting new native code into the XCode project that Unity created then Unity does export the #defines so you could then determine which version of Unity your native code needs to compile against.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The codes generated by different versions of Unity3D are not the same. I need to write different codes for my plugin depends on the Unity's version. So I thick it is the latter case in your answer. Now I am using the difference in generated codes between two Unity's versions to determine it. Thank you again.